# Which normal fonts support Unicode subscript characters?

Tags: unicode, fonts, subscript

I have a need to use the Unicode character 0x2091, a subscript e, rather than using markup for formatting the subscript. However, the usual-suspect fonts don't appear to include a glyph for this Unicode position.

Are there any Windows- or Office-included fonts that include this character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this website](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2091/fontsupport.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Just run `charmap.exe`.  Looks like **Arial**, **Courier New** and **Times New Roman** have it.

Comment: Always good advice to use charmap, but none of the fonts you mentioned support this character. Arial is closest, it has some subscript numbers, but no letters.

Comment: Interesting.  Windows 7's version of those fonts has it.  My original post was from a Win7 box.  My current box is Windows XP and doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect **Arial Unicode MS** to include such glyph.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately, it doesn't.