# Displaying Chemical Formulae - WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm currently creating a program where chemical formulae are being displayed in a text box. However, the formatting of these formulae is completely wrong and I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it.

For example, if I was to display the dissociation of H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub> in the program, I would have to display it like this:

```
H2SO4 ⇌ 2H+ + SO42-
```

Even non-chemists would agree that the formatting is off. For example, the number which shows how many atoms of an element there are should be a subscript, whilst the ion's charge symbol should be a superscript.

I'm just wondering if there's a way to display chemical formulae properly. It doesn't even have to be LaTeX, it could be as simple as displaying sub/superscripts.

Comment: Investigate the [`RichTextBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/richtextbox-control-overview-windows-forms) control.

Comment: TextBox can only have one Font. Either RTB or owner-drawing or try [these ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428803/which-normal-fonts-support-unicode-subscript-characters) and [this source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscripts_and_Subscripts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get several characters used in scientific formulas as sub- and/or superscript in many or most Unicode supporting fonts.

Here is an example that uses `Consolas 14pt`:

```
label1.Text = "H" + '\u2082' + "SO" + '\u2084' ;
```

[image]

It will work as well for TextBoxes or other Controls.

Here is a [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscripts_and_Subscripts) on wikipedia.